# ¿Cómo mostrar una cadena cada tres palabras, usando punteros?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

char s[100];

int main()
{
    char *ps = &s[0];
    cout<<"\n Ingrese la cadena: ";
    gets(s);
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++, *ps++)  {
        cout<<*ps;   }  
    _getch();
}
```

Como puedo mostrar una cadena cada tres palabras?, por ejemplo si ingresando la cadena:

```
Yo soy nuevo en programación, me gustaría aprender mucho y ser muy bueno en esto
```

A continuacion debería mostrar:

```
Yo          soy               nuevo
en          programación,     me
gustaría    aprender          mucho
y           ser               muy
bueno       en                esto.
```

Comment: Hola Nas_04 por favor incluye el código que hase intentado hasta el momento y que parte es la que no te sale. Si no lo intentas tu primero no esperes que otros lo hagan por ti.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Como puedo mostrar una cadena cada tres palabras?

Pues una buena idea sería dividir la cadena de entrada por palabras e imprimir palabra a palabra insertando un retorno de carro (`\n`) cada 3 palabras:

```
for (int id_palabra{}, id_ultima_palabra = frase.size();
    id_palabra < id_ultima_palabra; ++id_palabra)
{
    if (!(id_palabra % 3))
    {
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << frase[id_palabra] << '\t';
}
```

El código que has pegado para obtener la frase de entrada tiene una serie de problemas:

1. `*ps++` incrementa el contenido de ps, así que estás modificando la cadena entrada.
2. `_getch` no es portable, (casi) cualquier nombre que empiece por un guión bajo `_` está reservado por el estándar o para ser usado por librerías; he intentado compilar en gcc y no ha funcionado.
3. `cout<<*ps<<endl` muestra siempre la primera letra de la cadena leída, pues la expresión `*ps++` no avanza el puntero (ver primer punto).
4. `endl` no suele estar bien considerado dentro de bucles pues *flushea* el contenido del `stream`.
5. Usas arrays estáticos para leer los datos, eso está mas asociado con el estilo C, el estilo C++ suele usar más las estructuras de datos de la librería estándar.

Mi propuesta es  [[la siguiente]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/NqaksQYJLkmlw1n8):

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> frase{};

    // Lee hasta llegar al enter
    while (std::cin.peek() != '\n')
    {
        std::string palabra{};
        std::cin >> palabra;
        frase.push_back(palabra);
    }

    for (int id_palabra{}, id_ultima_palabra = frase.size();
        id_palabra < id_ultima_palabra; ++id_palabra)
    {
        if (!(id_palabra % 3))
        {
            std::cout << '\n';
        }

        std::cout << frase[id_palabra] << '\t';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### Editado

> como podría ser utilizando punteros?

No lo hagas. O si quieres hacerlo con punteros, no etiquetes la pregunta como [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b); las nuevas tendencias del lenguaje lo están encaminando hacia el desuso de punteros y hacia el uso de otras estructuras de datos como punteros inteligentes.

Aún así, si insistes en usar punteros necesitarás:

1. Leer la entrada en un buffer.
2. Utilizar dos punteros para marcar el inicio y el final de cada palabra.
3. Seguir la premisa anterior para imprimir.

Mi propuesta es  [[la siguiente]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/37nYxz1dZ2jGl1NN):

```
char frase[100]{};

gets(frase);

const char *inicio = frase;
const char *fin = strchr(inicio, ' ');
int linea{};

while (fin)
{
    char palabra[100]{};
    strncpy(palabra, inicio, fin - inicio);

    if (!(linea++ % 3))
    {
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << palabra << '\t';

    inicio = fin + 1;
    fin = strchr(inicio, ' ');
}

std::cout << inicio;
```

Observarás que el código es notablemente más largo y complejo; además: dado que no existe mecanismo para imprimir sub-cadenas mediante punteros, debe copiarse cada palabra a un buffer intermedio (con lo que el código es algo menos eficiente)...

... es más, dado que el control del bucle se realiza con el puntero `fin`, la última palabra se debe imprimir fuera del bucle, con lo que requeriría repetir (otra vez) el código de añadir el salto de línea (yo no lo he hecho).

Así que insisto: no uses punteros.

1. El código se complica.

   - Es más propenso a errores.
   - Es más difícil de leer.
   - Es más difícil de mantener.
2. Debes gestionar manualmente los recursos.

   - Se deben apuntar los punteros a memoria correcta.
   - Los buffer tienen un tamaño fijo, pudiendo desbordarse, esto debería controlarse.
3. Aleja el código de las tendencias del C++ moderno.

Comment: como podría ser utilizando punteros?

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres que las columnas estén bien definidas lo primero que tienes que hacer es conocer el tamaño de la palabra más larga y ajustar las columnas en base a ese ancho.

Una vez tienes esa información vas recorriendo la lista de palabras y las imprimes usando el ancho fijo que ya conoces... cada 3 palabras introduces un salto de línea y listo.

Algo así:

```
void PrintStrings(
    const std::vector<std::string>& words)
{
  size_t max_length = 0;
  std::for_each(words.begin(),words.end(),
                [&max_length](const std::string& word)
                { max_length = std::max(max_length,word.length()); });

  const char sep[3] = {' ',' ','\n'};

  size_t index = 0;
  std::cout.setf(std::ios::left);

  for (auto word : words)
  {
    std::cout << std::setw(max_length)
              << word << sep[index];
    index = (index+1)%3;
  }

  std::cout.unsetf(std::ios::left);
}
```

Comment: Por que todos son tan pro y yo soy tan malo? :(. Buena respuesta.

Comment: @SalahAdDin No se los demás pero 5 años que llevo programando en C++ y todas las semanas aprendo cosas nuevas